# How to fine tune FC1 and FC2 in VGG-19 PyTorch?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I need to fine tune pretrained [VGG-19](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SxXe.png) with pytorch. I have these specific tasks:

1. Finetune the weights of all layers in the VGG-19 network.
2. Finetune the weights of only two last fully connected (FC1 and FC2) layers
   in the VGG-19 network. And this is the only information given to me.

VGG-19 structure is like below:

```py
VGG(
  (features): Sequential(
    (0): Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (1): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (2): Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (3): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (4): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
    (5): Conv2d(64, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (6): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (7): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (8): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (9): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
    (10): Conv2d(128, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (11): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (12): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (13): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (14): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (15): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (16): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (17): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (18): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
    (19): Conv2d(256, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (20): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (21): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (22): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (23): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (24): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (25): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (26): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (27): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
    (28): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (29): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (30): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (31): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (32): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (33): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (34): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (35): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (36): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
  )
  (avgpool): AdaptiveAvgPool2d(output_size=(7, 7))
  (classifier): Sequential(
    (0): Linear(in_features=25088, out_features=4096, bias=True)
    (1): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (2): Dropout(p=0.5, inplace=False)
    (3): Linear(in_features=4096, out_features=4096, bias=True)
    (4): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (5): Dropout(p=0.5, inplace=False)
    (6): Linear(in_features=4096, out_features=1000, bias=True)
  )
)
```

I tried to do first task like this and i think it is correct:

```
model = models.vgg19(pretrained=True)

for param in model.parameters():
    param.requires_grad = True

model.classifier[6] = nn.Linear(4096, len(class_to_idx))
```

But i couldn't figure out second task, i tried this and i am not sure:

```
model2 = models.vgg19(pretrained=True)

for param in model2.parameters():
    param.requires_grad = False

# Set requires_grad to True for FC1 and FC2
for param in model2.classifier[0].parameters():
    param.requires_grad = True

for param in model2.classifier[3].parameters():
    param.requires_grad = True

# Modify the last fully connected layers for the number of classes in your dataset
model2.classifier[6] = nn.Linear(4096, len(class_to_idx))
```

How to do second part? Should i keep the `model2.classifier[6]` or define a new Sequential structure?

Answer (score 0):

You've mostly got the right idea. Small steps for implementing the second task:

1. Load the pretrained VGG-19 model.
2. Freeze the weights of all layers except for the last two fully connected layers (FC1 and FC2). If you are defining a new Sequential, you won't have the pretrained weights since pretrained weights are not available, so the approach would involve training the layers from scratch rather than fine-tuning existing weights
3. Optionally, modify the last layer to fit the number of classes in your dataset.

As you said above, the structure of the VGG-19's classifier section is:

```
     (classifier): Sequential(
        (0): Linear(in_features=25088, out_features=4096, bias=True) # FC1
        (1): ReLU(inplace=True)
        (2): Dropout(p=0.5, inplace=False)
        (3): Linear(in_features=4096, out_features=4096, bias=True) # FC2
        (4): ReLU(inplace=True)
        (5): Dropout(p=0.5, inplace=False)
        (6): Linear(in_features=4096, out_features=1000, bias=True) # Original output layer
      )
```

The code for updating only FC1 and FC2 (and the final classifier layer if you choose to modify it) will be updated during training, while the rest of the network remains unchanged:

```
    import torch.nn as nn
    from torchvision import models
    from torchvision.models import VGG19_Weights
    
    # Load the pretrained model
    vgg19_model = models.vgg19(weights=VGG19_Weights.IMAGENET1K_V1) # since 0.13, the argument 'pretrained' has been deprecated and may be deleted in the future
    
    # Freeze all layers' weights in the model
    for param in vgg19_model.parameters():  # get all the parameters of the model
        param.requires_grad = False  # these layers won't be update during training
    
    # Unfreeze weights of last two fully connected layers (FC1 and FC2)
    for param in vgg19_model.classifier[0].parameters():
        param.requires_grad = True  # will be updated during training
    for param in vgg19_model.classifier[3].parameters():
        param.requires_grad = True  # will be updated during training
    
    # (Recommended) Modify the last layer for your number of classes
    class_to_idx = TODO
    num_classes = len(class_to_idx)
    model.classifier[6] = nn.Linear(4096, num_classes)
```

The last fully connected layer (initially with 1000 output features for ImageNet) is replaced with the number of features equal to the number of classes in your dataset, and this is the recommended (if not essential) approach. If your task requires a different number of classes, you must adapt the model to output the correct number of possibilities. Another thing to consider is that, while your task may have the same number of classes as ImageNet, the classes themselves are likely to be different. Retraining the output layer helps the model to better discriminate between the classes specific to your task.

Comment: Thank you for your answer i hope you're right!

Comment: You're welcome! Maybe not in this case, but (in the future, if you have any further questions about ML) I think it would be clearer to someone if you mention some additional facts, such as I am developing a model for task X, the dataset contains Y classes, and so on